# How to add a boost query using SolrQuery

Tags: php, solr, solr-query-syntax

I am using SolrClient to connect with the database and following the example from https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php

I am trying to generate the query which I created through the dashboard of solr

> > URL/shop/select?q=*&sort=brand_logo_value+desc,created+desc&start=0&rows=12&facet=false&indent=true&fq=!final_price:0&fq=!img_flag:0&omitHeader=true&fq=(v_index_flag:1+OR+v_index_flag:4+OR+v_index_flag:99)&fl=id,store_for,store_id,user_id,product_title,final_price,store_from,seller,product1,website,product_id,company_name,category_name,sub_category_name,discount_percentage,list_price,affiliate_name,v_index_flag,parent_id,category_name_small,sub_category_name_small,type_small&group=true&group.field=parent_id&group.sort=final_price+asc&bq=uniq_text:(%22refurbish%22^-1000)&bq=brand_logo_value:(%221%22^5)&fq=category_name_small:%22electronics+and+appliances%22&fq=sub_category_name_small:%22air+conditioners%22&json.facet={categories:{type:terms,field:cat_subcat_type_small,sort:{parent_unique:desc},facet:{parent_unique:%22unique(parent_id)%22}}}&wt=json

What I am doing is passing the entire URL to a php page and exploding into individual part and adding creating the query

```
$query = new SolrQuery();
        foreach ($sections as $field) {
            $cut = explode("=", $field);
            echo "<br>" . $cut[0] . "===>" . $cut[1];
            switch ($cut[0]) {

            case 'fq':
                $query->setFacet(true);
                $query->addFilterQuery(str_replace("+", " ", $cut[1]));
                break;
            case 'sort':

                $cut2 = explode(",", $cut[1]);
                $SortOrder['asc'] = SolrQuery::ORDER_ASC;
                $SortOrder['desc'] = SolrQuery::ORDER_DESC;
                foreach ($cut2 as $slice) {
                    $bite = explode("+", $slice);
                    $query->addSortField($bite[0], $SortOrder[$bite[1]]);
                }
                break;

            case 'bq':
                $cut2 = explode(":", $cut[1]);
                $dismaxQuery = new SolrDisMaxQuery();
                $dismaxQuery->addBoostQuery($cut2[0], $cut2[1]);

                break;

            case 'group.sort':

                $cut2 = explode(",", $cut[1]);
                $SortOrder['asc'] = SolrQuery::ORDER_ASC;
                $SortOrder['desc'] = SolrQuery::ORDER_DESC;
                foreach ($cut2 as $slice) {
                    $bite = explode("+", $slice);
                    $query->addGroupSortField($bite[0], $SortOrder[$bite[1]]);
                }
                break;

            default:

                $query->setParam($cut[0], $cut[1]);
            }

        }
```

The code is not yet optimized YET. All are working fine but the BoostQuery(bq). I don't see any function in SolrQuery class to add this but have seen one in SolrDisMaxQuery https://php.net/manual/en/solrdismaxquery.addboostquery.php

But this is not adding the bq to the current SolrQuery object obviously.

So I have two question

1. Is there a method to add a boostquery with SolrQuery object
2. Is there a method in which I can directly execute the URL passed and get the result.

## EDIT1:

If anyone find ways to optimize the code or recommendation for logic change, It will really hep me.

## EDIT2:

Is there a method where I can execute a query directly using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creating an object and setting a value on it - and then doing nothing more with it won't do anything useful. So this part doesn't affect anything:

```
$dismaxQuery = new SolrDisMaxQuery();
$dismaxQuery->addBoostQuery($cut2[0], $cut2[1]);
```

Instead, create the query as a `SolrDisMaxQuery` instead of as a `SolrQuery`:

```
$query = new SolrDisMaxQuery();

foreach ($sections as $field) {
   ...
}
```

That way you can set the parameters that are specific to the DisMax query parser.

`SolrDisMaxQuery` extends `SolrQuery`, so it can be used in the same way as your previous class.